# Independent facet grids based on multiple data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

If I have two datasets on the same plot, can I have two independent facets on that plot, each corresponding to a different data set?

For example, in a scatter plot, one can split one data in the x direction, one can split the other data set in the y direction.

Consider, for example, the following code, where I am trying to split `d1` for values of the X axis less than 0.5 and bigger than 0.5,
and similarly for `d2` and the y axis. This runs, but I don't understand why I get the result i do.

It is possible that `ggplot2` is simply not designed to do this. I don't have an application in mind, I'm just trying to understand the
limits of faceting, and playing with examples is easier than trying to understand the code.

```
library("ggplot2")

splitvec <- function(v)
{
  if(v<0.5)
    return("L")
  else if(v>=0.5)
    return("R")
}

set.seed(1)
x1 <-  runif(5, 0, 1)
y1 <-  runif(5, 0, 1)
xsplit <- sapply(x1, splitvec)
d1 = data.frame(x=x1, y=y1, X=xsplit)
x2 <-  runif(5, 0, 1)
y2 <-  runif(5, 0, 1)
ysplit <- sapply(y2, splitvec)
d2 = data.frame(x=x2, y=y2, Y=ysplit)

r = ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=d1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_grid( ~ X) +
    geom_point(data=d2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_grid(Y ~ .)
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can do something like :

```
       facet_grid(Y~X)
```

Since that  grid faceting is applied sequentially. Note that you can't use `facet_wrap` in this case.
 Here I am rewriting your code to use different factors for each split variable (X,Y).

```
d1$X <- ifelse(d1$x<0.5,'d1.L','d1.R') 
d2$Y <- ifelse(d2$x<0.5,'d2.L','d2.R')
```

It is better to use different colors for each data to understand what happens to your data.

```
r = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=d1, aes(x=x, y=y),col='blue',size=10) +
  geom_point(data=d2, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  facet_grid(Y~X,scales="free")+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. First, you wrote: `d2$Y <- ifelse(d2$x<0.5,'d2.L','d2.R')`. I'm guessing that should be `d2$Y <- ifelse(d2$y<0.5,'d2.L','d2.R')`. The result of this is similar to your picture above, but isn't quite what I wanted. I wanted the unit square divided vertically and horizontally at 0.5, with the 10 points all in the appropriate positions. Instead, the two left facets each have duplicates of the 3 d1.L points, with the upper and lower facets each containing the points corresponding to d2.L and d2.R respectively. But maybe what I want isn't possible with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Also, thanks for your improvements to my plot. Indeed one should color the different dataset points differently. Also, I didn't think of using `ifelse`, since I'm not that familar with R.

Comment: P.S. I suppose one would get the effect I wanted if all the points were in the same dataset.